# Correctly Overlay DC.JS (D3) canvas elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, dc.js

It seems that there's somethings specific to canvas implementation of DC.JS's scatter plot, that when resizing the window, the canvas element doesn't respect the positioning of the axis. due to the movement of the title

**pre-window resize**
[image: pre-window resize]
**with canvas**
[image: with canvas]
**without canvas**
[image: without canvas]

It seems likely this is caused by [absolute positioning](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/5d984c840e168aede1a4338d086d9f376118e885/src/charts/scatter-plot.js#L147) of the canvas element.

I'm trying to find a workaround, but haven't been able to as there's no group around the two DOM elements:

```
<div data-css-1gb1n6i="" class="dc-chart" style="position: relative">
  <span data-css-m549sg="">reset</span>
  <label>Gains or Losses</label>
  <svg width="922" height="200" style="position: relative; z-index: 1">...</svg>
  <canvas
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="1660"
    height="296"
    style="
      width: 830px;
      height: 148px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 42px;
      z-index: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
    "
  ></canvas>
</div>
```

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-54aw9n?file=EventScatter.tsx) (resize viewer to see error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your analysis: without putting both of them inside another div, I don't know how to put the canvas at the same position as the SVG.

dc.js doesn't do very well with extra content inside the div, even though that's the only supported place for reset and filter display controls.

Indeed, by the time I looked at your stackblitz it was exhibiting another bug due to the reset button and gains and losses label:

[image]

The SVG is shifted down by the text, but the canvas is not. Not sure why this is not present in your screenshots.

I think the only easy solutions will involve making the reset and label absolute positioned

```
  <label style={{position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0}}>{title}</label>

const ResetButton = (props: any) => {
  const style = css({
    // padding: rhythm(0.1),
    display: 'inline',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    '&:hover': {
      background: '#ddd',
    },
  });
```

or making the svg absolute positioned to 0,0

```
  eventScatterChart.on('pretransition', chart => {
    chart.select('svg')
      .style('z-index', 1)
      .style('position', 'absolute')
      .style('left', 0)
      .style('top', 0)
    chart.select('canvas').style('z-index', 0)
  })
```

I tried each of these and they "worked".

[image: label overlap]

They leave you having to position the label and reset button manually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the title, Gains and losses, and the axis labelling will fit next to each other if the  window is wide enough. When it is narrower the system puts the axis labelling beneath the title and all is well but as you increase the window the two move side by side and as they are both relative the Gains and losses pushes the axis labelling to the right.

I'm not sure what you have control of, but the simplest workaround seems to be to put a line break after the end of the title: `Gains and losses<br>`

If you can't alter that but can alter the CSS you could do a `clear:both` in the label.

Comment: Thanks, that does work for the simplified example, but I have both x/y padding in my actual code that creates an offset even with the <br />

Comment: Could you put up an example that doesn’t work with either br it clear and I’ll have another look. Which element has the padding?